# Regular expression to match repeated strings

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics

I am trying to make a regex that will

- match if the string exclusively is constructed with strings from a set of strings.
- not match if there is any other string in there.

examples for a set of strings that is ['xyz', 'a', 'b']:

- 'xyzab' == true
- 'xyzxyzabbb' == true
- 'aaabb' == true
- '' == true
- 'd' == false
- 'aabbbbd' == false
- 'zxy' == false

I am URL matching :/

Comment: Use: `^(?:xyz|[ab])*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex: `^(?:xyz|[ab])*$`

```js
var regex = new RegExp('^(?:xyz|[ab])*$');
var input = ['xyzab', 'xyzxyzabbb', 'aaabb', '', 'd', 'aabbbbd', 'zxy'];

for (var i = 0, l = input.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(input[i], '->', regex.test(input[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of string {"str1", "str2", ..., "strN"}, write the regex as follows:

```
^(str1|str2|...|strN)*$
```

Where

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `(...)` matches any of the strings
- `*` means that the one above may be repeated from 0 to infinite times
- `$` matches the end of the string